# how to change the pressed state of a button in sencha touch

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am working on mobile web app using sencha touch. I created a button using following code

```
 {
            xtype: 'button',
            cls: 'messagesBtn'
}
```

And in App.scss I added following css which changed background of this button to an image

```
.messagesBtn {
  height: 50%;
  background: url(../images/home.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Now this css works but when I press that button then it does not it removes that images and add another state to it which I don't want. I want when user presses this button then another images should be replaced with the current one. **How can I achieve this?**

**UPDATE**

I changed my code and add pressedCls

```
{
            xtype: 'button',
            cls: 'messagesBtn',
            pressedCls: 'x-button-pressed'
}
```

And here is the css

```
 .messagesBtn {
  background: url(../images/home.png) no-repeat;
 } 

 .x-button-pressed {
    background: url(../images/appointments.png) no-repeat;  
 }
```

above does not work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without having to change the code of your button you can use this CSS:

```
.messagesBtn {
     // Your CSS for the normal state
 } 

 .messagesBtn.x-button-pressing {
     // Your CSS for the pressing state
 }
```

[Example here](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#PHRyc)

**Update**

Relevant read: [CSS Priority Order](http://hungred.com/useful-information/css-priority-order-tips-tricks/)

**Also, always use the Web Inspector or Firebug to check if your CSS is applied to the right element and if it's not being overridden by another CSS class**

Answer (score 3):

You can use [pressedCls](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Button-cfg-pressedCls) config of your button which is `the css class to add to the button when it is pressed`:

```
pressedCls: 'x-button-pressed'
```

Then you can apply any css style using that css class:

```
.x-button-pressed {
    background: url(image-pressed.png) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: weird, it should work, you can try changing your css to this: `background-image: url('../images/appointments.png') !important;`

Answer (score 0):

First assign an `ID` in your button property, then on `tap event` replace the `class` on that particular assigned ID. You should create another class for `pressed` mode. Hope it works..

Answer (score -1):

Add a [tap](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Button-event-tap) event listener to the button and then change the pressed class for your button.

```
{
    xtype: 'button',
    cls: 'messagesBtn',
    listeners: {
        'tap' : function () {
              ...   
        }
    }

}
```